# Find the date difference in ElasticSearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch

Let's say I have documents with the following fields: 
`{field1, field2, startdate, enddate}`

I need to run some queries where some of the conditions will require the difference between the `startdate` and the `enddate`

In standard SQL, an example could be:

`SELECT *,(2010-01-01-startdate) as diffstartdate, (2010-01-01-enddate) as diffenddate FROM Table1`

How can I achieve this in elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Script Fields` is what you need.

```
 {
 "query" : {
   "match_all": {}
 },
 "script_fields" : {
     "difference_between_two_dates" : {
        "script" : "groovy.time.TimeCategory.minus(new   java.util.Date(2010-01-01),new java.util.Date(doc['dateCreated'].value))"

     }
  }
}
```

Make sure that dynamic script is enabled in `elasticsearch.yml`.

```
script.disable_dynamic: false
```

You can refer to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-request-script-fields.html for more information.
Hope it helps.

Comment: That worked great. Also, I would like to know how to do the same within a function where there is  a where condition. If I need the result as follows: `SELECT *,(2010-01-01-startdate) as diffstartdate, (2010-01-01-enddate) as diffenddate FROM Table1 where field1='abc'`

Comment: You can add your conditions in "query" clause.

Comment: When I used the script `"script" : "groovy.time.TimeCategory.minus(new java.util.Date(2002-01-01),new java.util.Date(2002-01-02))"` i got the result as `"0.001 seconds"`. Why is it not showing the number of days?