# Search in ElasticSearch with where condition

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have documents with the following fields:  `{field1, field2, costprice, sellingprice}`

I need to run some queries where some of the conditions will require the difference between the `costprice` and the `sellingprice`

In standard SQL, an example could be:

`SELECT *  FROM Table1 where costprice-sellingprice>0`

How can I achieve this in elasticsearch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the date difference in ElasticSearch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053111/find-the-date-difference-in-elasticsearch)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I wanted to know the method to specify a condition as in where clause within the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Still scripts is what you need:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "doc['costprice'].value - doc['sellingprice'].value > 0"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with script filter, like so.

### How to do your condition

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": {
                        "script": {
                            "script": "(Float.parseFloat(doc['costprice'].value) - Float.parseFloat(doc['sellingprice'].value) > 0"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Note that dynamic scripting is disabled by default

> Groovy dynamic scripting off by default from v1.4.3
>   Groovy dynamic scripting is off by default, preventing dynamic Groovy scripts from being accepted as part of a request or retrieved from the special .scripts index. You will still be able to use Groovy scripts stored in files in the config/scripts/ directory on every node. (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html)

Elasticsearch has disabled dynamic scripts by default. Of cource, you can enable it in the config, but it's better to use indexed scripts. It's simple to put your script in `price.groovy` in the `scripts` directory of Elasticsearch. Elasticsearch will index your script, so you can use it als follows:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": {
                       "script": {
                           "file": "price",
                           "lang": "groovy"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your `price.groovy` file looks like:

```
(Float.parseFloat(doc['costprice'].value) - Float.parseFloat(doc['sellingprice'].value) > 0;
```